# Protractor test not running shows 'weird error 8'

Tags: angularjs, protractor

When I tried to run protractor test using `sudo npm run protractor`. It show the  following in the terminal

```
> angular-seed@0.0.0 update-webdriver /home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web
> webdriver-manager update
```

selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

```
> angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor /home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web
> protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js
```

[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

> /home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:155
>                   throw e;
>                         ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
>       at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1123:19)
>       at Object.goog.loadModule (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1085:46)
>       at /home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1:6
>       at Object.Context.closure.goog.retrieveAndExecModule_ (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:135:8)
>       at :1:6
>       at Context.closure.closure.vm.createContext.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/*base.js:104:12)
>       at Object.goog.importScript* (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:879:9)
>       at Object.goog.importModule_ (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:900:14)
>       at Object.goog.writeScripts_ (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1323:16)
>       at Object.goog.require (/home/krishna/projects/main/clients/web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:663:14)
>   npm ERR! weird error 8 npm WARN This failure might be due to the use
>   of legacy binary "node" npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>   /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian   npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: `This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" npm WARN For further explanations, please read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian`, that aside, you really shouldn't be running it with sudo

Comment: see https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/254

Comment: Are you using 32bit operating system?

Comment: I am seeing this error presently on a Fedora system, so for me that rules out the suggested issue with node in Debian systems.